# Access Screen object from external javascript

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have an external Javascript script in a QtQuick project and I want to access the `Screen` object from there. In particular, I want to access the `width` and `height` of the screen from the external JS function.

Do you know how I can do that?  Is passing it into a function the only way available?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [using signals](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-expressions.html#connecting-signals-to-javascript-functions) is one way to do it, otherwise, just passing the values through functions.